# Active class binding to all buttons instead of one

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have a set of 3 buttons.

Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3

Whenever user lands on my page, I want one of them to be active, based on what phaseActive.name gives.

phaseActive is a computed property.

When I `console.log(this.phaseActive.name)` it gives me in console `Phase one`

I tried doing this

```
 firstPhase() {
      if(this.phaseActive.name === "Phase one") return true;
    },
    secondPhase() {
      if(this.phaseActive.name == "Phase two") return true;
    },
    thirdPhase() {
      if(this.phaseActive.name == "Phase three") return true;
    }
```

and then

```
<button :class="{'active': firstPhase}" v-if="index == 0" /> 
<button :class="{'active': secondPhase}" v-if="index == 1" /> 
<button :class="{'active': thirdPhase}" v-if="index == 2" />
```

But this doesn't seem to work for some reason, instead of only 1 being active, all of them are active. Why is this happening?

Comment: Do firstPhase, secondPhase and thirdPhase are computed properties or methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to execute the function like `firstPhase()`; you missed the brackets.

Then again why write 3 functions for that ? Try following:

```html
<button :class="{active: phaseActive.name === 'Phase one'}" v-if="index == 0" /> 
<button :class="{active: phaseActive.name === 'Phase two'}" v-if="index == 1" /> 
<button :class="{active: phaseActive.name === 'Phase three'}" v-if="index == 2" />
```

Its more clear to understand

Comment: I've tried that but I used " " instead ' ' and was getting errors. Now i know why. Also I have one more issue, whenever I click on other button, this buttons still stays active, but it should switch to false.
I have ```exact-active-class="active"``` in my buttons but it doesn't work, it switches to another button but the first one keeps active

Comment: @FriedRiceEater You should mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Comment: On click of the second button, are you changing `phaseActive.name` ?

Comment: No, phaseActive.name runs in background. I just want the active  class to be enabled when user lands on page, but able to switch the tabs normally.

Comment: then add `@click="afunction"`, this `afunction` method should change `phaseActive.name` to appropriate phase.